# VBA mystery runtime error - if code is called while validation list DropDown is open

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have an error, that occurs when you start a VBA macro while the dropdown of a validation list is open. First it occured in a rather big file from a user test. But it can be reproduced in even a mini test file (on several PCs - current m365 build).

So the user has a cell, where he can select a value from a validation list dropdown.
Also the user can start a VBA macro by clicking a form with an assigned macro.

BUT: When the user "opens" the dropdown of the validation list, DOES NOT SELECT a value, the list is still open, and now clicks the form... Runtime Error.
It does not even matter WHAT the macro tries to do. As soon as the code refers to the worksheet, workbook, cell, whatever, it breaks.

Even a most basic 'ThisWorkbook.Activate' breaks.

It is not a very common usecase of course, but it is frustrating to not see any reason or solution :) Maybe anyone here can help?

Thank you all!

Screenshot 1: Validation list open - without selecting value. Then click button to call macro.
Screenshot 2: Error on first code line.

Validation list

[image: 1]

Error message

[image: 2]

I tried different code lines, and some things are working. If I only have e.g. calculations, that dont refer to the workbook, like setting i=1 and put i in a msgbox, --> works fine.

But even 'application.ScreenUpdate' will break the makro.

Comment: You _can_ avoid the error by using an ActiveX button instead of a Shape

Comment: The `Form Controls` button and shape button have the issue. ActiveX works well.

Comment: Thank you both for the information. I did not know that and had no clue, this could be the issue. I wish there were more styling option though for the ActiveX.